# REST Service returning object aborts

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I am trying to implement REST service in my C# application to communicate with Android client. I struggle with C# part.

I followed this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178

This is how I run my service:

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRestService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
host.Open();
```

Very like in article linked above I have IRestService interface and RestService with methods *EchoWithGet(string s)* and *EchoWithPost* which i dont use and I will not talk about it more. I want to return UserClientInfo class which is the cause of problem I will describe later.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    UserClientInfo EchoWithGet(string s);
}
```

Here is implementation of EchoWithGet(...). It connects to another service and calls UserLog which should return *UserClientInfo*.

```
public UserClientInfo EchoWithGet(string s)
{
    service = (IService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IService), "tcp://127.0.0.1:7878/" + "Service");
    service.UserLog("username", "password", out uci);
    return uci;
}
```

UserClientInfo is quite complex object. I am not sure if I can return it by service. It is struct containing another structures inside which contains another structures.

```
[Serializable]
public struct UserClientInfo
{
    public ulong ClientId;
    public DatabaseManager DBManager;
    public string DisplayedName;
    public ChISDispositions Dispositions;
    public RegistrationInfo RegistrationInfo;
    public uint Right1;
    public uint Right2;
    public uint Right3;
    public uint Right4;
    public string SessionId;
    public string UserId;
}
```

When I run my service and point my browser to *http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=teststring* I get Connection Interupted error. Firebug is showing status Aborted on network tab. Service somehow crashes. I can debug it and see that UserLog() retunrs uci object well and service returns it but somewhere between browser and service it fails.

I tried to return completly new object:

```
 UserClientInfo uci = new UserClientInfo();
```

That works and returns xml with plain object.

---

Is there something I do wrong?

Are there some limitation of services I should know about?

Is there any log where I could see whats wrong?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Check to make sure you do not have cyclical dependencies in your UserClientInfo data structure.  If you do it will choke during serialization. That may be why a new UserClientInfo goes through but one populated with actual data does.

Comment: Most likely your problem is with one of these three types, DatabaseManager, ChISDispositions, RegistrationInfo. Is DatabaseManager a class? If so, have you tried setting it to null?

Comment: As you said - problem is in ChiSDispositions. If I set it null I get the output. There are some methods and constants inside ChiSDispositions. I also found there references to enum types. Could that be the cause? However everything I found there is serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in complex some parts of that complex object. Solution was to convert it to DTO.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any log where I could see whats wrong?

You can add  [WCF logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/govindr/archive/2006/11/01/debugging-wcf-traces-and-message-logs.aspx) in your web.config file.  You can then use S[ervice Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to read/monitor it.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
           <add name="sdt" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
     </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```